# mstsc /admin for Microsofts RDP for Mac OS X

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, mac-osx, rdp

How do I access the reserved admin session using Microsofts RDP client on my Mac? The equivalent to `mstsc /admin` on the Windows client.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have my Mac in front of me however in a version prior to 2.1.0, there is an tick box option on the Remote Client Connection setup for an admin connection. It is labelled connect as Administrator if I remember correctly.

For version 2.1.0 and greater, see Christian Muggli's article [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Console or Admin Session](http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2009/08/04/microsoft-remote-desktop-connection-console-or-admin-session/) shows how you can put the /console or /admin directly at the end of server name of the RDC client (Mac or Windows).

**Official confirmation on how to do this is via this Microsoft Help Article: [How to connect to the Server Console](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/rdc/item/7bb83716-72d8-45ce-aba3-286b57a456ea?category=8ccf8a64-7139-44f5-9e77-50f2ea3ff971)**

Comment: Can't finde the checkbox, this is the software I'm using: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx

Comment: Unfortunatly I can only confirm this when I get home, but I do recall it's an option somewhere in the settings screens. I don't have access to a Mac at work but use it regurlarly. Either way the second solution I provide is to official Microsoft method of connecting using the RDC client. However you need to ensure your running the latest version.

Comment: Awesome, the /console bit did the trick. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two programs I know of that are good for this.

The offficial : [RDC](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx)
The better option : [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/)

Edit:

To connect to the console in cord you can open it up and select; "connect to console session".

Diago's answer works for RDC

Comment: His question is not what to use but how to use it.

Comment: Yeh sorry; just noticed that one; was editing it to actually add in the instructions to connect to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac
Version 2.1.0 (100825)

Computer: computerName.school.edu /console

This is similar to PC syntax: C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe /v: computerName/admin

Comment: This answer doesn't quite make sense. Can you edit it to clarify how it resolves the original question?